# How to resize UIImage with given ContentMode?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

How to resize UIImage with some ContentMode? That is, not just resize it keeping it's aspect ratio, but instead, given the target size, resize it with the desired option (scaleAspectFill / Fit / etc).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and the quickest way is to use UIImageView and take a snapshot of it:

```
extension UIImage {
    func resizedImage(targetSize: CGSize, contentMode: UIView.ContentMode) -> UIImage {
        let imgView = UIImageView(image: self)
        imgView.contentMode = contentMode
        imgView.frame = .init(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        return imgView.snapshot()
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat(for: .current)
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds, format: format)
        return renderer.image { [self] context in
            layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
        }
    }
}
```